# Getting undefined on this.$refs.xx or this.$el on a rendered component in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I don't understand what's going on, it should be pretty simple but for some reason I'm getting `undefined` on a property that when I debug it, I can see it's there, is not undefined. The component has mounted, the function is being used within mounted and everything should be there and working. But Vue keeps saying it's `undefined`.

This is the template:

```
<template>
    <div class="AnimatedCounter">
        <span ref="counterText" class="AnimatedCounter-text">{{ count }}</span>
    </div>
</template>
```

```
mounted() {
    this.setCount(this.counter);
},
methods: {
    setCount: (val) => {
        /* $refs props and $el is "undefined" at runtime */
        const obj = this.$refs.counterText;

        anime({
            targets: this.$el,
            n: val,
            round: 1,
            duration: 500,
            easing: "linear",
            update: () => {
                this.count = obj.n;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

No matter what I do, keeps doing the same. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you include your component's template ?

Comment: @Seblor Added, it's super small. Not sure why Vue doesn't like this tbh. I'm starting to get mad hahaha.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is from the way you wrote your function.

You used an arrow function, which does not bind the `this` keyword to the Vue component. It most likely references the `Window`

You need to use the `function` keyword to declare your function like so:

```
mounted() {
    this.setCount(this.counter);
},
methods: {
    setCount: function (val) {
        const obj = this.$refs.counterText;

        anime({
            targets: this.$el,
            n: val,
            round: 1,
            duration: 500,
            easing: "linear",
            update: () => {
                this.count = obj.n;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh jesus. Thanks. It was this.